# How to use pipewire with puppeter

Tags: ffmpeg, pulse-audio, headless, xvfb, pipewire

I was using PulseAudio to redirect Puppeteer audio to a virtual audio sink, but I have encountered some issues. Now I want to switch to PipeWire instead.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? It's nice that you want to switch, so tell us what effort you have put into doing this so far, and specifically, where you're stuck now, eg. the actual question you need answered.

Comment: @music2myear this is an example https://github.com/mboussaid/xfp-streamer